# jQuery .load() page fragment by tagName

Tags: jquery

Is it possible to load a fragment by using an element's name?

```
$('.history').load('history.php section');
```

Where "section" refers to:

```
<section>
  ...
</section>
```

In this case the element is only used once on the page.

Comment: Yes. That is how `.load()` works.

Comment: Down vote for a valid question :(

Comment: I did not down vote but the tooltip on the downvote icon shows several reasons. One being that the questions does not show any research effort. Have a look at jQuery app online documentation for load. Just Google jQuery load and you find your answer.

Comment: I did research and read the jQuery documentation, but for some other reason (maybe a typo) using an element name wasn't working at first. Just sayin' I did some research before asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. According to [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load/#loading-page-fragments) any jQuery selector should be valid:

> If one or more space characters are included in the string, the portion of the string following the first space is assumed to be a jQuery selector that determines the content to be loaded.

Comment: Strange. For some reason it didn't seem to work when I first tried it; possibly just a typo on my part. Cheers.